# Can I use an iterator in global state in Rust?

Tags: rust, static

I want to use an iterator as global state in Rust. Simplified example:

```
static nums = (0..).filter(|&n|n%2==0);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it, but you'll have to fight the language along the way.

First, true Rust statics created with the `static` declaration need to be compile-time constants. So something like `static FOO: usize = 10` will compile, but `static BAR: String = "foo".to_string()` won't, because `BAR` requires a run-time allocation. While your iterator doesn't require a run-time allocation (though using it will make your life simpler, as you'll see later), its type is complex enough that it doesn't support compile-time initialization.

Second, Rust statics require specifying the full type up-front. This is a problem for arbitrary iterators, which one would like to create by combining iterator adapters and closures. While in this particular case, as mcarton points out, one *could* specify the type as `Filter<RangeFrom<i32>, fn(&i32) -> bool>`, it'd be closely tied to the current implementation. You'd have to change the type as soon as you switch to a different combinator. To avoid the hassle it's better to hide the iterator behind a `dyn Iterator` reference, i.e. type-erase it by putting it in a `Box`. Erasing the type involves dynamic dispatch, but so would specifying the filter function through a function pointer.

Third, Rust statics are read-only, and `Iterator::next()` takes `&mut self`, as it updates the state of the iteration. Statics must be read-only because Rust is multi-threaded, and writing to a static without proof that there are no readers or other writers would allow a data race in safe code. So to advance your global iterator, you must wrap it in a `Mutex`, which provides both thread safety and interior mutability.

After the long introduction, let's take a look at the fairly short implementation:

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref NUMS: Mutex<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u32> + Send + Sync>> =
        Mutex::new(Box::new((0..).filter(|&n| n % 2 == 0)));
}
```

`lazy_static` is used to implement the create-on-first-use idiom to work around the non-const initial value. The first time `NUMS` is accessed, it will create the iterator.

As explained above, the iterator itself is boxed and wrapped in a `Mutex`. Since global variables are assumed to be accessed from multiple threads, our boxed iterator implements `Send` and `Sync` in addition to `Iterator`.

The result is used as follows:

```
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(NUMS.lock().unwrap().next(), Some(0)); // take single value
    assert_eq!(
        // take multiple values
        Vec::from_iter(NUMS.lock().unwrap().by_ref().take(5)),
        vec![2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    );
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67b0c451fa07cbc28c6fc37159386a97)

Answer (score 1):

No. For multiple reasons:

1. Iterators types tend to be complicated. This is usually not a problem because iterator types must rarely be named, but `static`s must be explicitly typed. In this case the type is still relatively simple: `core::iter::Filter<core::ops::RangeFrom<i32>, fn(&i32) -> bool>`.
2. `Iterator`'s main method, `next`, needs a `&mut self` parameter. `static`s can't be mutable by default, as this would not be safe.
3. Iterators can only be iterated once. Therefore it makes little sense to have a global iterator in the first place.
4. The value to initialize a `static` must be a constant expression. Your initializer is not a constant expression.

Comment: Point #3 is not necessarily true - if the iterator is infinite, a global iterator makes a lot of sense. For example, a global defined as `get_next_id = itertools.count().__next__` is not unusual in Python.

Comment: If your goal is to create an object that is incremented every time you use it, then the pythonic way isn't the way to go. In Rust, I would use [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7a89b10c273f85d93a292466c20229bb). Although I'd still rather pass a state object, rather than relying on a global.

Comment: Just note that the comment was mine, not from the OP. I can only speculate about the OP's actual needs, but my `next_id` example was just an illustration of how a global iterator might be a useful thing.